# Problems with .to_timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

I am attempting to following the steps in [Pandas: add timedelta column to datetime column (vectorized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355816/pandas-add-timedelta-column-to-datetime-column-vectorized) to add a time delta column to my dataframe by converting a'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp' series.

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-07-25 09:26:28',2],['2020-07-25 09:26:2',10],['2020-07-25 09:26:30',203],['2020-07-25 09:26:31',30]], 
                      columns = ['Time','Load'])

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
print(df)
print(type(df["Time"][0]))
df_static['time_delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_static['Time'])
```

> However, I get the following error:

TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

> What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need times from datetimes convert to timedeltas convert datetimes to format `HH:MM:SS` by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```