# convert object to datetime . time format more than 24 hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I got  data that the time format include some rows that the time  is  more than 24 hours.

the data also incluse date parameter

time 26:00 mean the day after at 2:00

max time is 28:00

I want to create datetime parameter
but because the time parameter is an object it doesn't let me to it.
and when I try to convert it says "hour must be in 0..23: 24:00:02"

any suggestion what to do?

edit:
i need the date time

[image]

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ...which should contain exemplary data as text, not image. also, are you using pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: add timedelta column to datetime column (vectorized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355816/pandas-add-timedelta-column-to-datetime-column-vectorized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use to_timedelta and to_datetime from pandas.

```
df['date time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%y') + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

Comment: for the format provided by the OP, it might be good to set `format='%d.%m.%y'` (or at least `dayfirst=True`, depending on what comes first).

Comment: I've added the format argument - when I originally tested the code  it worked fine without it, that's why I didn't include it in my original answer.

Comment: sure, it works without, but pandas will use month-first by default - which is not what the OP has in his sample ;-)