# Increment initial time value in floating seconds?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an initial time value like `15:59:26.186000` (format `%H:%M:%S.%f`).

And a pandas DataFrame with a seconds as floats

```
SECONDS
0.44121
0.92844 
1.60995 
2.16770  
2.87059
```

Is there any way to add those seconds to the initial value? So first row would be `15:29:26.627`, etc.

Comment: Outside of pandas, you can use `datetime.timedelta`...

Comment: Check this question if it's useful to you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355816/pandas-add-timedelta-column-to-datetime-column-vectorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to convert the Series to a delta, and add it to a [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) version of the initial value:

```
s = pd.Series([0.44121, 0.92844, 1.60995, 2.16770, 2.87059])
t = '15:59:26.186000'
pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='s') + pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: Much appretiated. This gives output as datetime64. PS to_timedelta have unit parameter (not units).

Comment: To save time only without date df['Timing'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timing'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta` with `unit` to convert `SECONDS` to time and add:

```
df['SECONDS'] = pd.Timedelta('15:59:26.186000') + pd.to_timedelta(df['SECONDS'], unit='s')
```

You can also multiply:

```
df['SECONDS'] = pd.Timedelta('15:59:26.186000') + df['SECONDS'] * pd.Timedelta('1s')
```

Output:

```
                 SECONDS
0 0 days 15:59:26.627210
1 0 days 15:59:27.114440
2 0 days 15:59:27.795950
3 0 days 15:59:28.353700
4 0 days 15:59:29.056590
```

Comment: `'15:59:26.186000'` should probably be a datetime, not a timedelta

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, probably to OP. But a datetime without date doesn't make much sense to me, code runs in different day gives different output :-).

Comment: The default date is not today, but rather a fixed number. The output is deterministic in my answer.